# Selecting a random row in Django, quickly

Tags: django, performance, caching, random

I have a view which returns data associated with a randomly-chosen row from one of my models. I'm aware of order_by('?') and its performance problems, and I want to avoid using order_by('?') in my view.

Because the data in my model changes very rarely (if at all), I'm considering the approach of caching the entire model in memory between requests. I know how many records I'm dealing with, and I'm comfortable taking the memory hit. If the model does change somehow, I could regenerate the cache at that moment.

Is my strategy reasonable? If so, how do I implement it? If not, how can I quickly select a random row from a model that changes very rarely if at all?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the ids of your object, and its range you can randomize over the ids, and then query the database

Answer (score 0):

A better approach might be to keep the *number* of objects in your cache, and simply retrieve a random one when you need it:

```
item_number = random.randint(MODEL_COUNT)
MyModel.objects.all()[item_number]
```

Comment: How do I actually implement the cache? A global variable? What's the Django pattern for something like that?